# branch point in real and imaginary part of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-points, multivalued-functions

Is it possible to have branch point in both the real and imaginary part of a complex function f(z)? An example might be

\begin{align}
f(z) = u(\theta) + iv(\theta)
\end{align}

where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary components and are functions of $\theta$ only. A branch point exists at z = 0.

If so, is the contour integral around the branch point affected? The analysis I typically see shows

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\oint_C f(z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}) dz = 0
\end{align}

but in all those cases it is only the imaginary part that is multivalued.

Comment: Any such times $(1+i)$ is an example, right?